# How To Use Reflection To Find UserControls On A Page In A Nested MasterPage

Tags: c#, reflection, user-controls, master-pages, nested

I have a **CommonMaster** page that then contains a **ConfigurableReportsMaster** page.  I then have an **AutitLog.aspx** page.  Now, on that .aspx page I have multiple UserControls.  Some of these UserControls are inheriting from an **ISQLFilter** interface, but not all.

While on the .aspx, in a RunReport event (that currently successfully fires) I am manually calling a method of each UserControl (that is in the ISQLFilter interface) called `.GetWhereClause()`.

```
this.ucsStateFilter.GetWhereClause(ref sbWhere);
this.ucsStatusFilter.GetWhereClause(ref sbWhere);
this.ucsActivityType.GetWhereClause(ref sbWhere);
this.ucsVendorFilter.GetWhereClause(ref sbWhere);
this.ucsProducerFilter.GetWhereClause(ref sbWhere);
this.ucsNameFilter.GetWhereClause(ref sbWhere);
this.ucsPolicyFilter.GetWhereClause(ref sbWhere);
this.ucsShowAddressInfo.GetWhereClause(ref sbWhere);
```

This works great and does *exactly* what I need.  I would like though, for ease of use, is to just call one method, say `GetAllWhereClauses()` that would use Reflection to find all of the UserControls (that inherit the ISQLFilter interface.)  It sounds really simple and I have used reflection numerous times.  I would assume I could have just done:

```
Type t = typeof(AuditLog);
PropertyInfo[] pis = t.GetProperties();
```

But the UserControls are not there.  I can look at `this` in the QuickWatch window and see each of my UserControls.  I have tried a looping through each of the .Controls sets from the Page and deeper and I can successfully get to controls that I have on the CommonMaster page.  But that doesn't help me here.

Perhaps I am thinking too much about it.  If it would help, can I just get a list of all of the `"<%@ Register ... %>` items?  I suspect I am just missing one cast or something.

Thanks in advance,
Kevin

Comment: By default, aren't those controls declared as *protected* fields?  If so, the raw `t.GetProperties()` will not work.  You'll have to pass `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.  However, that got me further down the rabbit hole.  I had to use .GetFields instead:

Comment: However, I now see them, but I cannot do an `fi is ISQLFilter` or even `fi is UserControlBase` so I am somewhat stuck again.

Comment: OK - SUCCESS!  Thank you Kirk.  The solution is using the .GetValue method.
The code is as follows:

    foreach (FieldInfo fi in fis)
      if (fi.GetValue(this) is ISQLFilter)
        // Do Something